# How to calculate double limit in Maxima?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, maxima-software

I want to calculate a double limit in Maxima. For instance,$$\lim_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}$$
By the way, it is very interesting that I calculated it in "wolframalpha" yet it gave me the result $0$! I think the correct answer should be "does not exist": $$\lim_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{x^3 y}{x^6+y^2}=\lim_{x\to0,\ y=kx^3\rightarrow0}\frac{kx^6}{x^6+k^2 x^6}=\frac{k}{1+k^2}$$Am I right? Anyway, how to do it in Maxima? 
Thanks!

Comment: You're right. WolframAlpha doesn't indicate the existence of multivariable limit, I guess.

Comment: Looks like a sound argument!

Comment: But how to calculate in Maxima? Or the software cannot compute it?